# WiFi Range is bad on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: wireless, 17.10

I installed Ubuntu on my HP Stream 11, I was pleased to find out that my WiFi worked but the range is terrible. To have a good signal I have to be right next router.

How can I improve the quality of the signal?

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 21)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 21)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 21)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 (rev 21)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #4 (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 21)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller (rev 21)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Comment: I just posted the lspci just now I didn't post it in the comments because it was too long

Comment: Except this is different because the wifi was excellent sitting next to the router unlike the 16.10 problem where the wifi disconnects next to the router

Comment: @agamer569 Forget the description, just try the solution(s).

Comment: Do I have to enter all of those commands or am I missing something? If I am, tell me what I am.

Comment: You enter the commands to see what setting works best, then you set the module parameter.  Some people using Larry Finger's github driver might need a different setting than those using the original kernel driver.  The problem is the same, HP started using only one antenna wire with RTL8723BE chipsets a few years ago and this affects many of their laptops

Comment: The commands broke my laptop! I can  no longer have wifi! The WiFi option to choose what WiFi I want is no longer there!

Comment: When I type down in the better command, it says mod probe: Error: could not insert ‘rtl8723be’: invalid argument

Comment: Yes it does show

Comment: When I try doing modprobe 2(The one that worked better), it said could not insert ‘rtl8723be’” invalid argument

Comment: Use `echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` then `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be-ant.conf` then finally `sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be && sleep 15 && sudo modprobe rtl8723be`

Comment: I’ll try that when I get back home

Comment: I fixed it!  Remember echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=X" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be-ant.conf? I replaced the X with 2 and rebooted and the wifi range was great! No need for sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2.